# set padding of list in dropdown list asp net

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, padding

i want to set padding betweet list in dropdown list using asp.net, not the padding of the box but padding/spacing betweet one lit to other

[image]

- set distace between "Amnat Charoen" and "Amphawa"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953163/style-option-elements-in-select-list-add-padding-and-or-margins), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083652/how-can-i-add-padding-to-html-dropdownlist) may help

Comment: this is interesting have a look - http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/04/jquery-styled-dropdownlist/