# Increase select option padding

Tags: html, css

Here's my code

```html
<select>
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>World</option>
</select>
```

I want to increase the `<option></option>` padding, I know there is a trick when increasing the font size but I wanna know if there is another way.

Thanks !

Comment: Just add padding to the `option` tag - http://jsfiddle.net/ho6afhbg/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style Option Elements in Select List (Add Padding and/or Margins)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953163/style-option-elements-in-select-list-add-padding-and-or-margins)

Answer (score 0):

Don't style default form elements. Use something like select2 or chosen plugins.

```
$('.select').select2();
```

Than you will have full control over elements.

Answer (score -3):

```css
option{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>World</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't see any padding applied

Comment: same issue, not applying padding in this way.